# Pinch gesture for box2d body / cocos2d sprite

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, uigesturerecognizer

I want to detect pinches on a box2d body in cocos2d iPhone, but I'm not sure where to start. The objects are simple b2cirleshapes. I know ios has the uipinchgeasture recogniser but I don't know if that's the way to go or how to implement it on a box2d object. 
Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pinchGesture:)];
[self.box2d addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];
```

WIth this -

```
- (void)pinchGesture:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinch {   
if (pinch.velocity < 0) {
    //close pinch
}
else {
    //open pinch
}
```

}

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something here because it says 'instance method -addGestureRecognizer not found' when I try to add it to the box2D body or the sprite.

Comment: Fixed it - edited your answer, the gesture recogniser needs to be on the openGLView (http://stackoverflow.com/a/5019536/459116 ). Thanks for your help, once the edit goes through I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Yes, that will work. I wasn't sure what you view object was named.