# How to make swipe gesture in cocos2d iphone?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

How can I make swipe gestures in `cocos2d` iphone/ipad in all directions? When swipe touches (passes at) on a sprite I want to perform a function at that time, like i want to cut that object when swipe at that sprite.

Answer (score 3):

You should look for cocos2d and gesture recognizer. Check this post

[cocos2d-iOS - Gesture recognisers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985917/cocos2d-ios-gesture-recognisers)

and google will help too...

Answer (score 1):

`UISwipeGestureRecognizer` might give you a problem because it only supplies you with the coordinates of the place where the swipe started (it only calls a handler once per swipe).

See: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

I would use `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.  This calls a handler every time the pan is updated (i.e. every time the finger moves during the swipe).  You can then figure out which sprite your pan/swipe is passing over.

Comment: thanks a lot for your kind help can you give me some code example please