# swipe and jump effects in iphone gaming with cocos2d and box2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I have a question.How can I achieve the jumping up and down effects (swiping left and right effects too.) in iphone gaming using cocos2d and box2D just like in temple run and subway surfers apps.Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Fails the fundamental question "what have you tried"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to look at [UISwipeGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html). For help with getting swipe gesture recognizers working with Cocos2D, [look here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985917/cocos2d-ios-gesture-recognisers)

The short rundown is this:

1. Set up your gesture recognizer (direction, number, selector/target).
2. Attach gesture recognizer to the glView
3. Set up event to fire when a swipe is detected. This is where you'll do the jump up/down stuff.
4. Tear down the gesture recognizer when you no longer need it.

A side note, a little bit of [research](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553) does wonders. All of this information is available with a quick google search.

Comment: Why did you downvote for my question.Is there anything wrong in clarifying my doubt? I would appreciate if you don't do that next time.Anyway thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: Your question was ill-formatted, and you did not do your own research before posting. Looking at the vote count, I was not the only person to feel that way. I did, however, try to be nice by providing you with a starting point.